# How DHCP Server handles multiple DHCPDiscover messages at the same time

Tags: dhcp

If two or more clients send DHCPDiscover at the same time, what would a DHCP Server do?
would it broadcast one IP for all the DHCPDiscover messages or it'd send a different IP for each DHCPDiscover message?

P.S: DHCPRequest and DHCPAck haven't happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

The DHCP server would normally not receive really two requests at the same time. It handles one request at a time that he receives probably by a socket function such as recvfrom. The DHCP protocol RFC 2131 says as follows: “The server may choose to record the address as offered to the client.“. Therefore it would be totally correct if the server responds with the same IP address in two consecutive DHCPDISCOVER messages. Conflicts are resolved later when a DHCPREQUEST is issued.